# How to change the starting day in Gnome calendar (Arch)?

Tags: configuration, gnome, archlinux

Since there is no GUI option to edit the default starting day of the week in the gnome calendar, how can one change it from Sunday to Monday?

Answer (score 5):

Step by step:

- Find out what locales you have installed via

  > locale -a
- For me I only had en_US.utf8 which makes weeks start from Sunday. If you have another locale that makes weeks start from Monday (such as en_GB.utf8) you can skip the next step
- Edit /etc/locale.gen so that a locale that has weeks that start from Monday is also uncommented (such as en_GB.utf8). Save and generate the locale with

  > locale-gen
- Now that you have the appropriate locale installed (check with locale -a to confirm it's there) open /etc/locale.conf, quite likely you'll only have one line at the top to the effect of LANG=<your_original_locale>.
- Add an entry underneath it for LC_TIME with your newly installed locale (for example LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8). Save and reboot, changes should take effect on startup.